# Calling a function twice without interference in C

Tags: c

I have a function that reads data from a serial line and processes it, simplified:

```
void serialData(int port){
  static uint8_t byte;
  static uint8_t store[];
  //read one byte from specified port
  //store this byte in the array
  //process the data
}
```

I need to read data from two different serial lines in a "ping pong" system and process the data in the same way for each line.

```
while (true){
  serialData(port1);
  serialData(port2);
}
```

This does not work as the data from port1 and port2 gets mixed in the array on each successive call.

I would like to only have the code for the function typed out once and then somehow reference the code using two different names so the variables do not interfere, is there a better solution beyond just copy/pasting the same code with a new name?

I have tried #define, for example:

```
#define port1Data serialData
#define port2Data serialData
```

and pointers:

```
void (*port1Data) (int) = &serialData;
void (*port2Data) (int) = &serialData;
```

but successive calls to the two renamed functions still interfere.

Comment: The function has static data?

Comment: How do they interfere? If they access the same static variables, then changing the name or making a pointer to them won't work, you need to have seperate data being accessed. This concept is called [Reentrancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing))

Comment: What is the *real* problem you need to solve? What is the function supposed to do? Do you have threads? Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: “I want to call this function multiple times using different names” — **why**? This requirement doesn’t seem to make sense. As for the actual question, you need to post the actual function (minimal example) and the actual calls for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. This question is way to vague. Ill delete and repost with more specific info.

Comment: @EricThornton You can (and are encouraged to) edit the question instead of deleting and reposting.

Comment: This problem is why traditional functions like `strtok()` have been superceded by reentrant versions like `strtok_r()`. Instead of using a static variable in the function, you pass an additional parameter that holds the function's state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to remove the static data from the function

```
#include <stdio.h>
int function(int n) {
    static int foo = 0;
    foo += n;
    return foo;
}
int main(void) {
    function(10); // returns 10
    function(-4); // returns 6
    printf("%d, %d\n", function(1), function(-1)); // UB; functions call mess with each other
}
```

See https://ideone.com/c1kW51

To remove the static data, I'd do something like

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct fxdata {
    int foo;
};
int function(int n, struct fxdata *p) {
    p->foo += n;
    return p->foo;
}
int main(void) {
    struct fxdata f1 = {0};
    struct fxdata f2 = {0};
    function(10, &f1); // returns 10
    function(-4, &f2); // returns -4
    printf("%d, %d\n", function(1, &f1), function(-1, &f2));
}
```

See https://ideone.com/aePprq